# PHP cURL odd behaviour

Tags: php, curl, get, timeout

I'm trying to parse a page for which I've to first log into that site with a username and password. So I started with a php cURL script to log into the page by using GET method, but problem is that I'm receiving a timeout error everytime, however long timeout period I set.

Login Page: http://myaccount.comeconnect.com/jsp/Login.jsp

URL used in cURL: http://myaccount.comeconnect.com/servlet/MyAccountLogin?loginMode=2&username=user&password=pass&QuickNavigation=Disabled

with valid, user and pass values.

Now when I use this URL in browser, I get logged in easily. So I'm little confused as to why I'm getting timeout errors.

PHP code is not on the same server.

PHP Code:

```
    //create array of data to be posted
    $post_data['loginMode'] = '2';
    $post_data['username'] = $_GET['user'];
    $post_data['password'] = $_GET['pass'];
    $post_data['QuickNavigation'] = "Disabled";

    //traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
    foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
        $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
    }

    //create the final string to be posted using implode()
    $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);
```

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];

//create array of data to be posted

$post_data = array( 'loginMode' => '2',
                    'username' => $user,
                    'password' => $pass,
                    'QuickNavigation' => "Disabled");


//create the final string to be posted using implode()

$post_string = http_build_query($post_data, '', '&amp;');

//Params for cURL

$ckfile = './cookie.txt'; 
$url = 'http://myaccount.comeconnect.com/servlet/MyAccountLogin?'.$post_string;
$timeout=10;
$userAgent= "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1";

//create cURL connection

$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,$timeout); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo curl_errno($ch) . '-' .curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: `http_build_query()` is your friend :)

Comment: Also, why are you storing GET params in `$post_string`?

Comment: Why aren't you POSTing the POST string?

Comment: I was earlier posting the post string, but I was getting the same error "timeout". So I tried to check if GET works, by firing up the URL in my browser and it worked so I thought maybe I should go with GET, but still "timeout" error

Comment: KK... Read about http_build_query().. Its just fancy way of doing wat I did here, anyway I used it and still no difference... Still 28-connect() timeout error

Comment: Set CURLOPT_VERBOSE to true, and compare the headers sent by cURL to the headers sent by your browser (i.e. via the WebKit inspector).

Comment: "supplied argument is not a valid cURL handle resource" error on using CURLOPT_VERBOSE along with CURLOPT_STDERR (used file handler with this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host `myaccount.comeconnect.com` appears to be preventing connections from non-customers. You're most likely receiving the error because you're not on an IP address that is allowed to connect and unfortunately, there is no way to fix that.

Comment: How did you check that? I would like to confirm that

Comment: @kirpalsingh - If you want to confirm, you can e-mail or call them. I tried from a few of my servers and was unable to connect from any of them. The fact that it doesn't disconnect right away seems to indicate that it's firewalled.

Comment: Thanx, I ain't asked them but used different ISPs to open this site and all of them failed to connect. It explains all the odd behaviour..